# Parse - splitting up my app.js file

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm not very knowledgeable on all the technologies that [parse](https://www.parse.com/) uses.

My `app.js` file is almost 10 000 lines long, and I consider this *WAY* too large. I want to split up the `app.js` file into parts.

Example: When the user goes to the "chat" section, he can create a new chat item, reply to an existing one, or edit one of his own. The routes for those 3 items are `/chat/new`, `chat/reply/:id` and `chat/edit/:id`.

I want to move those 3 functions to a `chat.js` file, which will then hold all chat related routes/functions in the future.

However, I have no idea where I should import or require the `chat.js` file. I haven't found anything that explains this in a way that I can understand. Please let me know if more information is required from my side if my question isn't clear.

Comment: You need to use AMD modules.  
Check out the [examples](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#examples) on the [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) site.

Comment: Add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done. I also posted a link on there that would help you get started with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up your code into **`modules`**.

There are 2 ways you can do that:

**CommonJS**: This is a synchronous approach, and is used in `node.js` (Although you *can* use `AMD` modules if you'd like). You can check out the [CommonJS wiki](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) for more info.

**AMD (`Asynchronous Module Definition`)**: This is what you want to use if you target browsers, or if you want async loading for some reason in your server-side javascript. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is probably the most widely used library for `AMD` modules.

You can start by reading this post - [Writing Modular JavaScript With AMD, CommonJS & ES Harmony](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) which has some nice examples of how you would go about using either one, and some general tips to follow when writing modular javascript.